# Error in subquery statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When i try to update the statement with below query. the error result is showing like in the heading

```
UPDATE STAG 
     SET STAG.TOT_POLICY_AMT =  (select replace(convert(varchar,convert(Money, TEMP.TOT_POLICY_AMT),1),'.00','') 
from #MONTHLY_PAYMENTS_REPORT_TEMP TEMP)
     FROM #MONTHLY_PAYMENTS_REPORT_TEMP STAG
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `SELECT` from your query and run your query like below:

```
update STAG
set TOT_POLICY_AMT = replace(convert(varchar, convert(money, TOT_POLICY_AMT), 1), '.00','')
from #MONTHLY_PAYMENTS_REPORT_TEMP STAG
```

You can simplify it even more with:

```
update MONTHLY_PAYMENTS_REPORT_TEMP 
set TOT_POLICY_AMT = replace(convert(varchar, convert(money, TOT_POLICY_AMT), 1), '.00','')
```